# Husband and wife applying together for an Australian tourist visa. Do we apply as a group or separately?

Tags: visas, australia, family

We are a husband and wife applying together for an Australian tourist visa. Do we apply as a group (creating a group ID) or separately from a single account?

We will be traveling on our own with relatives in Australia issuing an invitation letter and a sponsorship declaration.

Comment: Please don't use allcaps.

Comment: The rules may vary as to type of visa, group affiliation, your citizenship, and the intended duration of your trip. Thus: what passports do you carry, and how long do you intend to stay in Australia?

Comment: what did you end up doing, can you please share ? I have same question

Answer (score 2):

According to the Australia's [**Department of Home Affairs**](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/lega/lega/form/immi-faqs/immiaccount-multiple-visa-applications-payments) (excerpted):

> [**ImmiAccount**](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa/immi) is the front door to our online services. ImmiAccount accepts all online visa and citizenship applications except for Electronic Travel Authority (ETA) applications.
>
> **Can I submit multiple applications and/or payments in ImmiAccount?**
>
> Yes. [ImmiAccount](https://online.immi.gov.au/lusc/login) will let you submit multiple online applications and pay for these applications at the same time. For example, if you and your family are applying for visitor visa applications, one member of the family can create and manage all the applications through their ImmiAccount, and pay for all these applications at once. Payment can be made by credit card in Australian Dollars (AUD) for all online applications submitted through ImmiAccount.