# Can me and my gf apply to AU tourist visa together?

Tags: paperwork, australia, tourist-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

Me and my girlfriend are planning to visit Australia as a tourists. However we need to apply for a tourist(600) visa which requires us to provide bank statements. I have a fairly high paid job, good bank record(balance and monthly flow) while she earns a lot less than me thus having not so good bank record which means she has a lot less chance to get her visa approved.

A question is: can we apply for a tourist visa together providing my financial record as a source of funding for us both?

Comment: Does your girlfriend’s financial situation show she can afford the costs of the trip in her own right? The purpose of providing bank statements is more than just how much she earns - this question relates to the U.K. but the principles are similar https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: This is one of those cases where being non-married partners is legally *being nothing*. E.G. what happens if you break up in Australia and decide not to fund the remainder of your partner's stay or flight home. Now the partner must rely on public funds or seek employ, and is likely to overstay the claimed visit duration (which matters). That ticks the top 3 boxes on immigration's mission statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119843/husband-and-wife-applying-together-for-an-australian-tourist-visa-do-we-apply-a

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica that sounds far-fetched. I've had friends visit here on visitor visas with their non-married partners. The fact that they weren't married was never an issue. There were income disparities between partners as well.